# Is there a published object model for EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for a document that describes the relationships between the AWS EC2 components, e.g. instances, subnets, security groups, regions, etc. A UML class diagram would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I found three resources that may help you, but nothing exactly what you mentioned in the question:

1. [AWS In Plain English](https://www.expeditedssl.com/aws-in-plain-english)... does help you translate Amazon speak to normal human speak
2. [AWS Architecture Center](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/): An official resource from AWS showing webinars, whitepapers, video interviews, case studies and architecture diagrams from both major AWS users and idealized cloud use cases
3. [AWS Technical Essentials](https://aws.amazon.com/training/) training courses, some online and some multi day long training classes.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that was helpful though not quite what I was looking for.